# powershell compare 2 arrays output if match

Tags: powershell

I have two arrays that I want to compare the items of

I have array A [hi,no,lo,yes,because] and array B [mick,tickle,fickle,pickle,ni,hi,no,lo,yes,because]

so I want to search every item in A and compare to every item in B and if there is a match return "there is a match"

Comment: What have you tried? What errors have you gotten? Please show what efforts you have made so that we can help fix things, we don't just hand out code without some effort on your part.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to know if A is found inside B, with items in sequence, or do you want to know if all of the items are in B, but not neccessarily in sequence? Or do you want to know if the arrays are the same, and in sequence? Be more specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One-liner:

```
foreach ($elem in $A) { if ($B -contains $elem) { "there is a match" } }
```

But it may be more convenient to count matches:

```
$c = 0; foreach ($elem in $A) { if ($B -contains $elem) { $c++ } }
"{0} matches found" -f $c
```

Or if you want to check if arrays intersect at all:

```
foreach ($elem in $A) { if ($B -contains $elem) { "there is a match"; break } }
```

Or if you want to check if $A is a subset of $B:

```
$c = 0; foreach ($elem in $A) { if ($B -contains $elem) { $c++ } }
if ($c -eq $A.Count) { '$A is a subset of $B' }
```

Finally there's Compare-Object cmdlet which is actually better than all of the above. Example (outputs only elements that are present in both arrays):

```
Compare-Object -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent $A $B
```