# Powershell Compare 2 Arrays of Hashtables based on a property value

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array, iteration, hashtable

I have one array of hashtables like the one below:

```
$hashtable1 = @{}
$hashtable1.name = "aaa"
$hashtable1.surname =@()
$hashtable1.surname += "bbb"

$hashtable2 = @{}
$hashtable2.name = "aaa"
$hashtable2.surname =@()
$hashtable2.surname += "ccc"

$hashtable3 = @{}
$hashtable3.name = "bbb"
$hashtable3.surname = @()
$hashtable3.surname += "xxx"
$A = @($hashtable1; $hashtable2; $hashtable3)
```

I need to iterate though the array and I need to find out duplicates based on hashtable[].name

Then I need to group those hashtable.surname to hashtable[].surname so that the result will be an array of hashtables that will group all for name all the surnames:

```
$hashtable1.name = "aaa"
$hashtable1.surname = ("bbb","ccc")

$hashtable3.name = "bbb"
$hashtable3.surname = ("xxx")
```

I was looking into iterating to empty array

+

I have found this link:

[powershell compare 2 arrays output if match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290652/powershell-compare-2-arrays-output-if-match)

but I am not sure on how to reach into the elements of the hashtable.

My options:

1. I was wondering if -contain can do it.
2. I have read about compare-object but I am not sure it can be done like that.
   (It looks a bit scary in the moment)

I am on PS5.

Thanks for your help,
Aster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group your array items by the names using a scriptblock like so.
Once grouped, you can easily build your output to do what you seek.

```
#In PS 7.0+ you can use Name directly but earlier version requires the use of the scriptblock when dealing with arrays of hashtables.
$Output = $A | Group-Object -Property {$_.Name} | % {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        Surname = $_.Group.Surname | Sort-Object -Unique
    }
}
```

Here is the output variable content.

```
Name Surname
---- -------
aaa  {bbb, ccc}
bbb  xxx
```

**Note**
Improvements have been made in PS 7.0 that allows you to use simply the property name (eg: `Name`) in Group-Object for arrays of hashtables, just like you would do for any other arrays type. For earlier version though, these particular arrays must be accessed by passing the property in a scriptblock, like so: `{$_.Name}`

**References**

[MSDN - Group_Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1)

[SS64 - Group Object](https://ss64.com/ps/group-object.html)

[Dr Scripto - Use a Script block to create custom groupings in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-a-script-block-to-create-custom-groupings-in-powershell/)

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks. Improvements are always appreciated. Regarding the first assumption though, while I would never normally do `{$_.Name}` when I can do just `Name`, it is to note that Windows Powershell 5.1 have a discrepancy on that regard. Normal array of PSObject will work as you describe but arrays of hashtables won't group properly if you do not use the scriptblock to describe the property. This was changed along the way since after I read your comment, I also tested the behavior in PS 7.2 and it worked as one would expect.

Comment: Excellent point re `{$_.Name}` - thanks for pointing that out. PowerShell (Core) 7+ has made progress toward interchangeable use of hashtables and objects, as is the case here, but it's not quite there yet.